# how to implement relations on firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have to save history of actions that happen on my website. What im currently doing is saving the userData to the action since I dont think firestore has easy relations.
The problem comes when I change the userData on user, then history is displaying the old userData instead of the new one. So the solution that im thinking of is looping through all his actions and changing all the userData there. Or is there something else I can do? Is it possible to create firebase cloud founction, that would search for 10 recent activities from any user, and append the that releated user data to it? or would that take too long? how to handle relations in firestore overall? Since if I do it all on frontend I would have to make 10 user data requests to display them.

firebase relations are generating too many fetches if used on frontend, how do I solve that?

Comment: What are the exact relations you want to implement?

Comment: first of Firestore relation is denormalized. for your case a cloud function would be a great solution. and `the solution that im thinking of is looping through all his actions and changing all the userData there` is what Firestore suggested in their docs. what I'd do is to update the action's document related to that user, and I think the relation would be is each document action has the user id.

Comment: Soif the action document has the user id, I wouldn't worry about the user data if it changed because I have the user id in the action document. so, when I want to get the user action, I can get them easily. and vice versa I can know this action document user belong to which user from user id saved in the action document.